# Errors encountered while processing linux-image-5.3.0-18-generic

Tags: apt, grub2, kernel

I've been having this problem since the beginning of this morning where I haven't been able to install this through `apt-get upgrade`, also tried `dpkg --configre -a` as well as `apt-get install -f`. Not entirely sure what is causing the multitude of errors as can be shown bellow.

```
(Reading database ... 263079 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.3.0-18-generic (5.3.0-18.19+1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-18-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 37: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.3.0-18-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.3.0-18-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.3.0-18-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Just to inform everyone adequately I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 on an X1 Carbon 7th generation, the linux portion of my laptop is on an encrypted LVM setup (doubt that is causing problem) and I am dual booted with Windows 10.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There seems to be something wrong in your `/etc/default/grub`. Could you add its content into the question?

Comment: Line 37 of the ```/etc/default/grub``` file had an issue, referencing theme file that didn't exist, removing it allowed the update process to proceed, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

As shown with the above two comments, contents of `/etc/default/grub` on line 36/37 were the source of the issue. This problem has now been solved. Possibly user error on my part OR juts something strange when I setup the system originally (did not use the default installer for all steps, partitioning was done manually in terminal and `grub-install` was run after installation with the contents of the LVM virtual group manually mounted)

Will set this as the 'answer' in 2 days as stack exchange won't let me do it now